# Selecting row in tableview, removes custom cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a Viewcontroller with a Searchbar at the top with a tableview below. The tableview has a custom cell with 2 labels in it. My problem is that when i run the app and i select a row/cell everything inside the cell disappears. I then force the blank cell outside the visible area of the tableview, so it will be re-used. That's when everything inside the cell is back. Does anyone know why it behaves like this?

My Custom cell class (ContactCell.swift):

```
import UIKit

class ContactCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var lblContactName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lblContactTitle: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

My ViewDidLoad function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
}
```

My Delegate and Datasource:

```
extension contactsTabelViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("contactCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ContactCell

        if let label = cell.lblContactName{
            label.text = "This is a name"
        }
        if let label3 = cell.lblContactTitle{
            label3.text = "This is a title"
        }

        return ContactCell()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that caused this problem was that i returned `ContactCell()` instead of the variable `cell`

Solution was:
Change this:

```
return ContactCell()
```

to this:

```
return cell
```

in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function.